# Add a new stemmer to nltk

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, text-mining, stemming

I have this python function that works as expected. Is it possible to save the logic as NLP stemmer?
If yes, what changes needs to be done?

```
import itertools, re
def dropdup(mytuple):
    newtup=list()
    for i in mytuple:
        i = i[:-3] if i.endswith('bai') else i
        for r in (("tha", "ta"), ("i", "e")):
            i = i.replace(*r)
            i = re.sub(r'(\w)\1+',r'\1', i)
        newtup.append(''.join(i for i, _ in itertools.groupby(i)))
    return tuple(newtup)

dropdup(('savithabai', 'samiiir', 'aaaabaa'))
('saveta', 'samer', 'aba')
```

I will like the users to import something like this...

```
from nltk.stemmer import indianNameStemmer
```

There are a few more rules to be added to the logic. I just want to know if this is a valid (pythonic) idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First see https://www.python-course.eu/python3_inheritance.php

Create a file `mytools.py`

```
import itertools, re
from nltk.stem import StemmerI

class MyStemmer(StemmerI):
    def stem(self, token):
        itoken = token[:-3] if token.endswith('bai') else token
        for r in (("tha", "ta"), ("i", "e")):
            token = token.replace(*r)
            token = re.sub(r'(\w)\1+',r'\1', token)
        return ''.join(i for i, _ in itertools.groupby(token))
```

Usage:

```
>>> from mystemmer import MyStemmer
>>> s = MyStemmer()
>>> s.stem('savithabai')
'savetabae'
```

Comment: I wish there was a easy way to package it so that I could use pip install mystemmer

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, all you have to do is to inherit from the [StemmerI](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/stem/api.html#StemmerI.stem) class.

Comment: Can you show an example of how to use that class to write my own stemmer?

Comment: Just convert your function into the method  `stem`.